# Nilradical of the finite intersection is equal to the finite intersection of nilradicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am studying the theorem that any finite intersection of $P$-primary ideal is primary.
So, let $Q_i$ for $i=1, 2,\ldots, n$ be $P$-primary and let $Q$ be the intersection over $i$ of $Q_i$. I do not understand why the nilradical of $Q$ is equal to the intersection over $i$ of the nilradical of $Q_i$?

Would you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely you have enough experience asking questions now, for it to be useful for you to learn MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean radical where you say nilradical.

Let $I$ and $J$ be any ideals of the commutative ring $A$.
I claim that $\sqrt{I\cap J}=\sqrt I\cap\sqrt J$. The $\subseteq$
inclusion is clear. For the reverse inclusion, let $a\in\sqrt I\cap
\sqrt J$ then $a^m\in I$ and $a^n\in J$ for some $m$ and $n$.
Then $a^{m+n}\in I\cap J$ etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! In the second line, you mean for some positive integers m and n.